# JTextField size can't be changed

Tags: java, swing, size, awt, jtextfield

```
public class AddMult extends JFrame {
    public AddMult() {
    setSize(600, 600);

    txtEnterNum = new JTextField();
    txtEnterNum.setSize(100,50);
    lblEnterNum.setLocation(100, 150);
    add(txtEnterNum);
    txtEnterNum.setVisible(true);


    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}
I tried to create a form and a JTextField on it. But the problem is, my location and size doesn't work. The TextField is filling the whole form. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you ever remove txtEnterNum which exists before?

Comment: The answer that is currently accepted is the complete wrong way to go about sizing and positioning the text field. I (and many others) can give you the correct advice for doing so, but first we need to know how the entire GUI (along with any other components & labels etc.) is **supposed** to appear. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: BTW 1) A height of 50 is much taller than a text field would normally appear, unless it has a large font. 2) `txtEnterNum` the 'enter num' part of that name suggests that a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` might be a better programming approach, and also easier for the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The size is not "working" due to the default layout (FlowLayout) in your JFrame. This layout doesn't let you change the size or location of any object.
Try to use your own layout (modify x and y values in order to modify the size and location of your components):

```
setLayout(new LayoutManager() {
        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {



        }

        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {

        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {

            float modifierx = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/100;

            float Sizemodifier = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/50;

            float modifiery = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/150;

            int x=(int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/modifierx);

            int y=(int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/modifiery);

            int height =(int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/Sizemodifier);

            int DX =(int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/modifierx);

            int DY =(int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/modifiery);

            for(int i = 0; i<parent.getComponentCount();i++){

                if(i%2==0){

                    parent.getComponent(i).setBounds(x,y,x,height);

                    x+= DX;

                }else{

                    parent.getComponent(i).setBounds(x,y,x,height);

                    x=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/100;

                    y+=DY;

                }

            }
        }


    });
```

You have to set the layout in the constructor of the JFrame:

```
frame() {

    setSize(600, 600);
    setLayout(new LayoutManager() {...}

    txtEnterNum = new JTextField();
    txtEnterNum.setSize(100, 50);
    setLocation(100, 150);
    add(txtEnterNum);
    txtEnterNum.setVisible(true);


    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: The edit outlines an approach that takes all the existing problems of `null` layouts and wraps them in a custom layout. It is not an improvement. In fact, given it is just as bad but might fool newbies into thinking it is a more robust way of doing things, it is taking a step backwards. Ask yourself this, how does this custom layout manager account (and adjust) for all the factors mentioned in the first sentence of my initial comment? (Spoiler: it doesn't.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've changed the code the way I think It now adapts to each screen size. Please check it and if you think there is a way to improve it tell me.

Answer (score 0):

use `obj.setBounds();` to set the size and location of the obj in frame
or you could try to use layouts
you can read about it in : [Visual Guide to Layout Managers (java documentation)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).